# jQuery Autocomplete (devbridge) Ajax Serverside serviceURL Search File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using the DevBridge jQuery Autocomplete plugin with the ajax option (using serviceURL instead NOT lookup). I have a php file that queries the db (WordPress FYI) and gets all the results just fine. So when users type into my autocomplete field, it's showing ALL the results with their query highlighted. Apparently my server-side script is supposed to handle the searching and return ONLY the filtered results based on the user's on-the-fly input. I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.

I've found a ton of posts online stating this is how it's supposed to work but can't find any working examples of a serviceURL file that returns filtered results based on what the user is typing.

Here's the code I have so far...

My jQuery...

```
$('#product_sku_autocomplete').autocomplete({
      serviceUrl: '/blah/blah/ajax-product-sku.php', 
      minChars: 1,
      onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
      }
  });
```

the contents of my ajax-product-sku.php file. This gets all the various meta values for a custom field (sku) across all 'products'

```
  if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    require_once( '../../../../wp-load.php' );
  }

  global $wpdb;

  $term = $_GET['query'];

  $query = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = %s 
        AND p.post_status = %s 
        AND p.post_type = %s
    ", 'sku', 'publish', 'products' ) );

    $reply = array();
    $reply['query'] = $term;
    $reply['suggestions'] = array();

    foreach ($query as $sku) {
      $reply['suggestions'][] = array(
          "value" => $sku,
          "data" => $sku
      );
    }

    echo json_encode($reply);
```

The results if I access ajax-product-sku.php directly...

```
{"query":null,"suggestions":[{"value":"52N242","data":"52N242"},{"value":"52F230","data":"52F230"},{"value":"52F235","data":"52F235"}]}
```

So I'm getting my full list of results (properly formatted as far as I can tell) and the autocomplete field retrieves those BUT when you type into the autocomplete field it's showing ALL the results not just the ones that match what the user has typed in.

I suspect that I need to add the $term var somewhere within my db $query statement but not sure how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. Pretty simple solution but my sql chops are lacking obviously. Need to add a LIKE condition to the sql statement. Here's the revised ajax-product-sku.php file contents.

If anyone has a more efficient way to handle this from a coding or performance standpoint, I'd welcome the knowledge...

ajax-product-sku.php

```
  if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    require_once( '../../../../wp-load.php' );
  }

  global $wpdb;

  $term = $_GET['query']; // this is the var that autocomplete sends as users type.
  //$term = '1';

  $query = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = %s
        AND p.post_status = %s
        AND p.post_type = %s
        AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%{$term}%'
    ", 'sku', 'publish', 'products' ) );

    $reply = array();
    $reply['query'] = $term;
    $reply['suggestions'] = array();

    foreach ($query as $sku) {
      $reply['suggestions'][] = array(
          "value" => $sku,
          "data" => $sku
      );
    }

    echo json_encode($reply);
```